# Get dynamic table alias in Rails scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two scopes that are shared by the majority of my models. They have raw SQL that directly refers to the model's table name, and that doesn't play nicely with Arel:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  valid = lambda do |positive = true|
    if %w[validForBegin validForEnd].all? { |c| base_class.column_names.include?(c) }
      condition = "NOW() BETWEEN #{base_class.table_name}.validForBegin AND #{base_class.table_name}.validForEnd"
      condition = "!(#{condition})" unless positive
      where(condition)
    end
  end

  scope :valid, valid
  scope :invalid, -> { valid(false) }
end

# Sample usage

class Party < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :name,
    -> { valid },
    class_name: 'PartyName',
    foreign_key: :partyId,

  has_many :expired_names,
    -> { invalid },
    class_name: 'PartyName',
    foreign_key: :partyId,
end
```

Since my scope refers directly to the model's `table_name`, I can't join on both associations at once:

```
Party.joins(:name, :expired_names).first

# Produces this sequel statement

SELECT `party`.*
FROM `party`
INNER JOIN `party_name` ON `party_name`.`partyId` = `party`.`id`
AND (NOW() BETWEEN party_name.validForBegin AND party_name.validForEnd)
INNER JOIN `party_name` `expired_names_party` ON `expired_names_party`.`partyId` = `party`.`id`
AND (!(NOW() BETWEEN party_name.validForBegin AND party_name.validForEnd))
ORDER BY `party`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Note that both 'AND' conditions on the joins are referring to the table `party_name`. The second one should instead be referring to `expired_names_party`, the dynamically generated table alias. For more complicated Rails queries where Arel assigns an alias to EVERY table, both joins will fail.

**Is it possible for my scope to use the alias assigned to it by Arel at execution time**?

Answer (score 1):

I created this repo to help test your situation:
https://github.com/wmavis/so_rails_arel

I believe the issue is that you are trying to use the same class for both relationships.  By default, rails wants to use the name of the class for the table associated with that class.  Therefore, it is using the table name `party_name` for both queries.

To get around this issue, I created an `ExpiredName` class that inherits from `PartyName` but tells rails to use the `expired_names` table:
https://github.com/wmavis/so_rails_arel/blob/master/app/models/expired_name.rb

```
class ExpiredName < PartyName
  self.table_name = 'expired_names'
end
```

This seems to fix the issue in my code:

```
Party.joins(:name, :expired_names).to_sql
 => "SELECT \"parties\".* FROM \"parties\" 
INNER JOIN \"party_names\" 
  ON \"party_names\".\"party_id\" = \"parties\".\"id\" 
INNER JOIN \"expired_names\" 
  ON \"expired_names\".\"party_id\" = \"parties\".\"id\""
```

Let me know if it doesn't work for you and I'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This won't work exactly, since ExpiredName uses the same table as PartyName. However it did lead me to a working proof of concept: `class ExpiredName < PartyName; ALIAS = "expired_names_party".freeze; end`, and in my valid lambda: `table = defined?(self::ALIAS) ? self::ALIAS : table_name`. This won't work in ALL cases but it's a good start. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and in Party: `has_many :expired_names, -> { invalid }, class_name: 'ExpiredName', foreign_key: :partyId, inverse_of: :party,`

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  I didn't quite understand what you were doing, but now I think I do.  I updated the code in my repo to test the situation.  It seems like the database is smart enough to use the correct party_names table for each join statement even if it isn't using the alias.  I did need to change `Party.joins(:name, :expired_names)` to `Party.left_joins(:name, :expired_names)`, though.  Otherwise, you won't get any party back unless they have at least one valid and one expired name.  Let me know if that helps you.